# Foundation for category theory

Tags: logic, category-theory, foundations

Before a little premise:

It's well known that we can internalize the notion of category, functor and natural transformation in any category with enough structure: for instance we can define what an internal category is in every category with pullback, enriched category in monoidal categories (even if to prove most result we require a symmetric closed one) and also che define [internal category in every monoidal category](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+category+in+a+monoidal+category) in which the tensor product preserve equalizer.

Now, after some study I get that all these theories serve the purpose to internalize some categorical construction in categories rather different than set, and said theories indeed require classical (i.e. $\mathbf{Set}$-based) category theory (indeed they require the definition of monoidal category, category with some limits etcetc.

So for what I get now the problem is that in order to do category theory we need a category with enough structure (like we need $\mathbb Z$ or symmetric and linear group to do some group theory :) ).

Now for all of you we had the patience to read the premise here the question:

> Are there other foundational theories that seen in a set-theoretic meta theory have as models some (structured) categories, such that in these theories we can define a concept of category and develop all the classical result and constructions which can build in classical set based category theory? (even enriched category theory, higher category theory and so on)?

I thank in advance for any answer :)

Comment: are you perhaps looking for topos theory?

Comment: @IttayWeiss Not exactly, I'm looking for concrete categories in which develop category theory. For what I got topos theory require category theory and set theory as its basis to be fully developed. What I'm asking for is something that we could call a foundational category.
Hope I've been able to clear my doubts.

Comment: to describe an explicit category you will have to have some language first, which will have to be something like set theory. You can't avoid that. So I'm not entirely sure what you are looking for.

Comment: @IttayWeiss good point....give me some time. I'll try to reformulate the question in a different way. Meanwhile thanks for the comments.

Comment: @IttayWeiss I've edited the question.

Comment: I'm afraid it's still rather incomprehensible. What _is_ a category if not a set of objects and a set of morphisms? In the 1960s there were attempts (c.f. Lawvere) to directly develop an axiomatisation of the category of categories, but that's not how category theory is done today (probably for a good reason).

Comment: One thing to note is that their is not one category theory, their is a multiverse of category theories, at least one for each model of set theory. In other words, "category theory" will look different in different set theories (read set theories as something like models of ZF or some significant fragment thereof). I think what the OP is asking is what else lives in this multiverse of category theories. I have wondered about this myself, but I do not know how to make a precise question out of it. I think some knowledge of logic would help.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for thanks a lot @BabyDragon

Comment: Another related question is: can you found mathematics (or some chunk of mathematics) without some notion of a "collection". That seems tricky to me, since whenever we start writing things down, something is being collected in one form or another.

Comment: @BabyDragon Yes, but that's like saying that there is one "group theory" for each model of set theory. That is true in a very precise technical sense and yet almost completely irrelevant to mathematical practice.

Comment: @ineff It begins to look to me like you are asking what makes a 2-category look like a 2-category of categories. Some more recent work on this question revolves around ‘Yoneda structures’; see [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0606393), for example.

Comment: @ZhenLin, Yes and no. Yes in the sense that most, mathematics remains unchanged under change of base. No in the sense that category theorists sometimes find it convenient to work with universes from time to time. I personally find something like  "iteration of ZFC to NGB" to be pleasing to have around.

Comment: What about type theory: for what I get one can define what is a category in this theory. And clearly this is not a set theory in the classical sense of ZFC or NBG.

Comment: You might be interested in this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_theory#Relation_to_category_theory       It tells you how to go from category theory to type theory (which is the wrong way around).

Comment: @BabyDragon Thanks again

Comment: I also found this a few minutes ago. http://golem.ph.utexas.edu/category/2013/01/from_set_theory_to_type_theory.html#more